# MongoDB does compound index on multiple fields indexes the _id column by default or not?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I am not clear on whether the mongodb would use the index that I created or not.
Below is how my data looks like

```
_id: an string
field1: string
field2: array
field3: boolean
field4: integer
```

Now I created an [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) as below

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({"field1":1, "field2": 1, "field3": 1, "field4": 1});
```

Now suppose I issue the below query, prefix search on id and equality on the rest of the field

```
db.mycollection.find({"_id":/^abc/, "field1": "pqr", "field2": "xyz", "field3": true, "field4": 123});
```

would the above query use the compound index that I created above or not?
Do I have to include the **_id** as well during index creation as below?

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({"_id": 1, "field1":1, "field2": 1, "field3": 1, "field4": 1});
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use `explain` to find out the execution plan for your query given the defined indexes. Execution plan will say whether indexes are used and if so which ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now suppose I issue the below query, prefix search on id and equality
> on the rest of the field `db.mycollection.find({"_id":/^abc/, "field1": "pqr", "field2": "xyz", "field3": true, "field4": 123});`
> would the above query use the compound index that I created above or
> not?

There is a default unique index on the field `_id` and your index using fields `field1+field2+field3+field4`. The query optimizer can use *any* one of the two indexes. As I tried with similar data, index and query, I see that it used the default index on the `_id` field.

To verify if a query is using an index and which index is being used, use the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/index.html) method on the query. This generates a query plan which will show which index is used when the query gets executed.

> Do I have to include the _id as well during index creation as below?

You can include the `_id` field as part of the compound index. For example, as you had posted the index on `{"_id": 1, "field1":1, "field2": 1, "field3": 1, "field4": 1}`. Note that after creating the index there will be two indexes - one on the `_id` field and the new compound index including the `_id`.

The query will use the compound index to perform the read. You can verify that as well by generating a query plan using the `explain`.

Note, the index on the `_id` filed cannot be deleted (and user created indexes can be). To list the indexes on a collection, use the command `db.collection.getIndexes()`.

**Note on using compound indexes:**

- One of the factors to consider when using compound indexes is *query
  selectivity*. Selectivity is the ability of a query to narrow results
  using the index... See [Create Queries that Ensure
  Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/).
- Creating index on more fields can be an overhead while inserting data
  into the collection (as the index also needs creation). Also, a large
  sized index needs more memory during operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to include _id as well to make it a full index match else index will be used but partially. It will not be a COLLSCAN but numScanned and numReturned will not match exactly.

You may use mongo $explain to debug the indexes used in query planning

```
db.mycollection.find({"_id":/^abc/, "field1": "pqr", "field2": "xyz", "field3": true, "field4": 123})
    .explain("executionStats")
```