# How multiple indexes works on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

we have 3 cols `{'x','y','z'}`
and there are millions of records

when i create one by one index

```
{x:1}
{y:1}
{z:1}

collection.find({'x':'foo','y':'bar','z':'test'})
```

works faster

but when i do multiple indexes as `{x:1,y:1,z:1}`

```
collection.find({'x':'foo','y':'bar','z':'test'})
```

works more faster

so my question is what will happen for below find;

```
collection.find({'x':'foo','y':'bar'})
```

for index `{'x':1,:'y':1}`

for index `{'x':1,'y':1,'z':1}`

will they in same speed?

The second question is below indexes are same?

```
{'x':1,'y':1,'z':1} 
{'y':1,'z':1,'x':1}
```

Comment: I think this [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries) is the exact answer to your case, and they have example highly similar to your situation.

Comment: thanks,

so if i create {x:1,y:1,z:1} index

i do not need to create additional {x:1} for collection find({x:'foo'})

Comment: yes from my understandings :)

Comment: From the documentation, again, your second question has the answer that the two indexes are not he same. And, it also applies to your comment - refer the topic about Compound Index Prefix.

Comment: thanks @prasad_ 

so {x:1,y:1,z:1} index does supports collection.find({'x':'foo', 'z':'bar'}) ?

Comment: Also, see this post on using compound indexes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663992/mongodb-does-compound-index-on-multiple-fields-indexes-the-id-column-by-default/62669480#62669480